# Load query search results in modal instead of new page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-modal

**Edit:** Here is a screenshot: [Modal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8lPP.png)

**Edit**: I edited the code and I am no longer redirected to a new page when clicking the 'Search" button, but my output from index.php is still not showing in the modal. When I click 'Search', the modal pops up with an empty body. **How do I get my output from index.php to show in the modal's body?**

I have a search bar for users to enter a query. Upon clicking 'Search', a modal should appear with the query results.

My code isn't displaying anything in the modal window. When I click the 'Search' button, the modal window opens but immediately afterwards a new page is loaded with the query results.

How do change it so that the query results display in the modal window rather than a new page?

**index.php**

```html
<head>
  <title>Search</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter query"/>
   <input type="button" name="search" value="Search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">
   </form>
 </body>

<script>
  $('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault() // do not submit form
      // do get request
     $.get( 'search.php', { q : },function(e){
         // then show the modal first
         $('#mymodal').modal('show');
         // then put the results there
         $('#mymodal:visible .modal-container .modal-body').html(e);
     });
  });
</script>

 <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**search.php**

```html
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);

  include_once('db.php'); //Connect to database
  if(isset($_POST['q'])){
    $q = $_POST['q'];

    //get required columns
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `englishWord` LIKE '%$q%' OR `yupikWord` LIKE '%$q%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); //check for query error
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
      $output = '<h2>No result found</h2>';
    }else{
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['yupikWord'].'</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['englishWord'].'</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['audio'].'</h2><br>';
        $audio_name = $row['audio'];
        $output .= '<td><audio src="audio/'.$audio_name.'" controls="control">'.$audio_name.'</audio></td>';
      }
    }
    echo $output;
  }else{
    "Please add search parameter";
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: are you redirected to search.php after clicking on submit button?

Comment: @Dhiren yes, redirected to search.php

Comment: ok then please change type to "button" from "submit" and change **action="#"** instead of search.php in form tag and try...

Comment: @Dhiren okay I am no longer redirected. Now the modal pops up but there is nothing in the body. How can I get the output in search.php to show up in the modal?

Comment: please put a debugger in $.get call and check where and how you are getting the values in that and then set that data in modal-body. For now you are returning value but you are not setting that values in any html tags thats why nothing shows up.

Comment: I'm not sure how to put a debugger in $.get call. Do I need to put anything in modal-body?

Comment: This way,
`$.get( 'search.php', { q : },function(e){
         // then show the modal first
debugger
         $('#mymodal').modal('show');
         // then put the results there
         $('#mymodal:visible .modal-container .modal-body').html(e);
     });`
and check in chrome debugger what you are getting in data!

Comment: I am having trouble seeing in chrome debugger what I am getting in data. The script (that contains the $.get call) doesn't show anything when I hover over it. The script doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: please try this code,  `$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'search.php',
    success: function(data){
 debugger
        $('#mymodal').modal('show');
         // then put the results there
         $('#mymodal:visible .modal-container .modal-body').html(e);
    }
});
`

Comment: I posted a screenshot. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I have seen the screenshot. But my question is have you seen in chrome debugger what you are getting in data object at debug point?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this possible solution by following this changes
 - Remove Form tag
 - Add Onclick Listner on Search Button
 - First put content in Modal and then show Modal

**index.php**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.search').click(function () {
    var q= $('#q').val();

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            q: q
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // Add response in Modal body
            $('.modal-body').html(response);


            $('#mymodal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
});
```

```html
<head>
   <title>Search</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <!-- Script -->
   <script src='jquery-3.1.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Enter query"/>
   <input type="button" class="search" name="search" value="Search">
</body>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <!-- Modal body -->
         <div class="modal-body">
         </div>
         <!-- Modal footer -->
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```